# Unable to send messages to a MUC room

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework, multiuserchat

When I try to send a message to an XMPP MUC Room such as:

```
<message to="room@conference.chat.example.com" type="groupchat">
    <body>TEST</body>
</message>
```

The message will not be delivered to other participants in the room and I get this response from the server:

```
<message
xmlns="jabber:client" lang="en" to="karim@chat.example.com/resource" from="room@conference.chat.example.com" type="error">
<error code="503" type="cancel">
    <service-unavailable
        xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas">
    </service-unavailable>
    <text
        xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas" lang="en">User session not found
    </text>
</error>
<body>TEST</body>
```

Im using **ejabberd Community Server v20.07** installed into Docker using the [official image](https://hub.docker.com/r/ejabberd/ecs).

> The full `ejabberd.yml` configuration file that Im using can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/EyyXk1JY).

> The full server log can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/612QK86b).

The above error happen with different clients and not only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have configured this, and this is completely wrong:

```
hosts:
  - chat.example.com
  - conference.chat.example.com

modules:
  mod_muc:
    ...
```

I guess you didn't notice the option HOSTS in the MOD_MUC documentation: https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/modules/#mod-muc

Try something like this:

```
hosts:
  - chat.example.com

modules:
  mod_muc:
    hosts:
      - conference.@HOST@
    ...
```